# LINQ query to call instance method

Tags: c#, linq

I have written some code that has this form:

```
var  queryResult = from instance in someCollection
  where instance meets some criteria
  select instance;

foreach (InstanceType instance in queryResult.ToList()) {
    instance.SomeMethod();
}
```

This seems a bit redundant in that the query is iterating over the collection and then there is another iteration to invoke the method on all found instances. It would be nice to be able to invoke the instance method with in the query, rather than having to write an additional loop.

How could someone accomplish what the code above does with just a single query?

Comment: Depends on what the source is (db, collection etc..) and what does SomeMethod actually do.. Either way, we have a nice site for optimising your code:  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Also the query is not "iterating over the collection", it just creates an IQueryable or IEnumerable (depending on the type of linq you're using). Nothing is getting enumerated untill your foreach method there (you could have 1 000 000 000 elements or 1 element it would take the exact same time to evaluate queryResult, as long as you're not materializing it nothing happens)

Comment: I shortly learned after posting this question that the query will not until the foreach loop is executed. That explains why things I was trying to call the method never worked. I don't know if there is some explicit mechanism for invoking a query. If not I'm wondering that means I should be doing something different to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @Tron After reading your latest comment, seems like you are suggesting that your understanding of the problem has changed.. is that right? If so, feel free to post a new question..

Comment: I'm not sure that my understanding of the problem has changed necessarily. I think I just understand that while I was searching for answers before posting, why the things I was trying were not having any effect because I was trying to get everything to happen within the query definition itself, and since the query was never executed when it was just defined, nothing happened. I'm still wondering if maybe what I'm trying to do is better done some other way beside using a query, as it looks like it might be relying on a side effect. That is not completely clear to me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ForEach` to call `void` methods:

```
someCollection
    .Where(instance => instance meets some criteria)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(item => item.SomeMethod(param1, param2, ...)); // Use Foreach(SomeMethod) for methods w/no args
```

Comment: This doesn't change the fact that one is looping over the list twice (once to materialize the query with .ToList) and then again with ForEach. And besides that, invocation of ForEach is not even part of the query per se.. its a method invocation on the List.. and this approach only makes it look like one line of code with side effects.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the `.ToList()` from your code.. and you'd be looping over the collection only once..

In general, it is advisable to **not** have side effects in your queries.. and methods like `instance.SomeMethod()` are typically side effects..

Apart from removing the ToList call (which is really the additional and redundant loop here), the code snippet looks fine to me..

Comment: However, both collection needs to be in same type...! isn't it?

Comment: @gyan1991 - The final code uses for each to loop over the enumerable.. queryResult is an IEnuermable, and so is the List we get from ToList().

Comment: Even though you use IEnuermable, you still have to convert to a know type which is as same as your collection to read and re use in the code, isn't it?

Comment: The whole point of what I was trying to do was to find all members in a collection (an array in this case) that I can call a method on.

Answer (score 1):

Looks a little better. Im not sure of the actual number of iterations though.

```
foreach (var instance in someCollection.Where(instance meets some criteria))
{
    instance.SomeMethod();
}
```